Grafana dashboard to plot exact time a message processing took
I have a way to calculate how long a message processing took. For example,
M1, startTime = T1, endTime = T2, processingTime=T2-T1, user1
M2, startTime = T5, endTime = T6, processingTime = T6-T5, user1
I want to have dashboard in Grafana that says that :

M1, T1, processingTime
M2, T5, processingTime

Basically, that M1 came at T1 and took how much time, similarly M2 came at T2 and took how much time. How do I do that?

I dont know what metric type to use, i am computing the delta in my code as explained above.
